# Display compilation in inactive buffer

Tags: emacs

```
GNU emacs 23.2.1
```

I am using emacs on a netbook 10" screen size.

If I have 2 buffers open vertically to each other. When I compile the compilation show up in a new vertical buffer. However, now I have 3 buffers. However, with a small screen there is no room to see the errors.

I am wondering if there is a way to show the compilation in the inactive buffer.

I am using the following to display the vertical buffer:

```
; Always split vertiacally 
(setq split-width-threshold 0)
(setq split-height-threshold nil)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: When I compile is creates a \*compilation\* buffer that displays on the inactive side.  Does that not work for you, or do you not want to create the \*compilation\* buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
(setq split-width-threshold (ceiling (frame-width) 2))
```

#### Edit (Nov 24):

Maybe this will do:

```
(defun display-on-side (buffer &optional not-this-window frame)
  (let* ((window (or (minibuffer-selected-window)
                     (selected-window)))
         (display-buffer-function nil)
         (pop-up-windows nil))
    (with-selected-window (or window (error "display-on-side"))
      (when (one-window-p t)
        (split-window-horizontally))
      (display-buffer buffer not-this-window frame))))

(setq display-buffer-function 'display-on-side)
```

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. It still opened up a new buffer. Currently if I have 2 buffer side by side (buffer1, buffer2). If buffer1 has focus when I compile. Then I want buffer2 (inactive buffer) to display the compilation results. Thanks.

Comment: It works for me with a naked emacs (i.e., emacs -Q).  Perhaps it's other part of your .emacs file that causes the problem?  For example, does it set pop-up-windows to non-nil?

Comment: I don't have any thing like a pop-up-windows. What I have been experimenting with is this: ; Always split vertiacally 
(setq split-width-threshold (ceiling (frame-width) 2))
;(setq split-width-threshold 0)
;(setq split-height-threshold nil)
Thanks for your help